# How to make sure all ajax calls got executed successfully ( not completed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know this question has been asked multiple times before as how to execute function when all AJAX call has been completed. We can user jquery.stop() in this case.
But my requirement is different. I want to show confirm banner when all ajax call have been executed successfully. For different pages , I have multiple AJAX calls. I do not want to put any condition on each AJAX call success method.
Can any one suggest if there is any global way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: Its not clear for me what you're asking for, are you asking how call a callback when the ajax was sent, or are you asking how to globally define an algorithm that all ajax calls should use in a specific handler without writing it manually in each place you're using ajax (duplicating code)? Or both/none?

Comment: I want to show success banner when all ajax calls will be success. In some pages , I have 10 AJAX calls. When all theses ajax will have success response then only I need to show success banner or modal. My problem is  even though I put some condtion in each AJAX call of success function.. and later checked if its true to show banner. But  some calls executes early and some takes time. So I want to have global solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

your are searching for global event handlers:

https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

anytime when you call an ajax request you "see" it via `.ajaxSend()` and handle response via `.ajaxComplete()`